# Ruby data manager for multi-dimensional data

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array

I am looking for a RUBY module (probably a gem) for working with 2 or 3 or 4 dimensional data. No UI just the data management part. It's probably a veneer over an array. I also need sorting and filtering and other functions. For example, and this is just an example :)

```
a = MultiDim.new(2)
a.dim_name(0) = "Costs"
a.dim_name(1) = "Years"
a.load_data....
a.filter(:years, :non_nil)
a.sort(:costs)
a.acccess(years: 1990..1999) => a hash by costs.
```

etc. etc. etc.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

[daru](http://github.com/v0dro/daru) is a gem meant for data analysis in ruby.

It's under active development and you can expect some pretty exciting features in the coming weeks.

It works with 2 basic data structures, `Vector` and `DataFrame`.

You can first create a data frame:

```
df = Daru::DataFrame.new({costs: [100,200,300,400], years: [2013,2014,2012,2011]})
```

You can call a vector and sort it this way:

```
df.costs.sort
```

To filter data:

```
df.keep_row_if do |row|
  row[:costs] == 100
end
```

This will yield a DataFrame like this:

```
    costs years 
0   100  2013
```

For multi-dimensional data you can nest DataFrames inside a DataFrame.

This is my first answer so please forgive me for any misgivings!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Updated as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want Ruby's built-in [`Matrix`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html) class as a starting point.

Sorting is inherited from Enumerable, but I'd use [`sort_by`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) over [`sort`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort) for speed, simplicity and depending on your needs. `sort_by` seems to me like it'd be a more natural fit for dealing with multiple-dimension arrays.